# Split sentences with quotes in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am making a processing system for books, and as part of that I need a robust algorithm for splitting text into sentences.

The straight forward approach is to simply split the text based on occurences of the characters .?! , however a lot of books uses quotes heavily and this does not give the proper result. Consider the sentence:

'Come on!' he yelled. He was getting upset.

Which would be split into

1. 'Come on!
2. ' he yelled.
3. He was getting upset.

While we want this result:

1. 'Come on!' he yelled.
2. He was getting upset.

Now, we could detect wether the .?! characters are within quotes, and never split inside quoted text, however detecting what is within quotation marks and not is not trivial. Consider this sentence:

'What's going on?' he asked.

This would need us to detect the difference between a quatation mark and an apostrophe used for other purposes such as "that's", "The 69'ers'", "His 'n' Hers'" and so on.

We have no control of what kind of quote marks are being used. `Could be "quote", ‘quote’, 'quote', “quote”.` With apostrophe characters either like `"that's" or "that’s"` ... I am sorry if the differences are not easy to see here, but there are many different quote characters used.

Many of these cases are trivial, but we have to deal with worst case scanerios too, like the examples earlier.

At least in most cases the start of a quote is a different character than the end of the quote. For example:

‘We’ll be back in a couple of hours.’

So, this gives us a pretty solid indication of when the quote starts at least. Although, it is unclear which character ends the quote.

Anyone know of a good solution?

Edit: My existing code, dealing with the most trivial case where quote characters are different from apostrophes used:

```
    public static List<string> splitSentences(string text)
    {
        List<string> sentences = new List<string>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        bool insideQuote = false;
        for (int i=0;i<text.Length;i++)
        {
            char c = text[i];

            //Handle quotes properly
            if (isQuote(c))
                insideQuote = !insideQuote;
            sb.Append(c);
            if ( !insideQuote && isSentenceDelimiter(c) )
            {
                string s = sb.ToString().Trim();
                if (s.Length>0)
                    sentences.Add(s);
                sb.Clear();
                insideQuote = false;
            }
        }

        if (sb.Length > 0)
        {
            string s = sb.ToString().Trim();
            if (s.Length > 0)
                sentences.Add(s);
        }

        return sentences;
    }


    private static char[] splitter = new char[] { '.', '!', '?', '。', '！', '？', '\n', '\r' };
    private static bool isSentenceDelimiter(char c)
    {
        foreach (char d in splitter)
            if (d.Equals(c))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    private static char[] quotechar = new char[] { '"', '“', '”' };
    private static bool isQuote(char c)
    {
        foreach (char d in quotechar)
            if (d.Equals(c))
                return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using an existing library, eg http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: I see even more problems: Is it possible to have nested qouted sentences? I think I already read texts with nested quoutes.

Comment: 'Come on O'Malley, what's the problem? Is Ms. O'Malley's sinuses flairing up again?' yelled O'Brian.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Ouchy! OP: I'd take the 3rd party library option over doing this myself every time.

Comment: https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=nlp&type=Repositories

Comment: @Sinsro this is not that difficult however you have shown `0` effort on your part and sounds to me like you are wanting someone to provide a solution for you which if you understand the `String.Split()` function along with the string.Contains function you could get at this also `string.Replace()` function .. can you show us what you have tried on your own .if not look for a 3rd party free `Lib`

Comment: Natural language processing is **hard**. Even if you focus only on english there are enough edgecases to make a grown developer cry. There are no easy or simple solutions, and you need the work of language experts to handle it well. If you can define a list of required things to handle then maybe, *just maybe*, you can find a simple solution but to handle all that the english language can throw at you, I would say that is simply not feasible.

Comment: @MethodMan "this is not that difficult" Really? English is pretty much the quirkiest language out there. It's difficult. ***Really difficult***.

Comment: @spender if it were difficult then how is it hat there is code for this already.. come on... http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/ why re-invent the wheel if the wheel is out there for use..? anyway Cheers..!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The pedant in me feels I should correct " Is Ms. O'Malley's sinuses flairing up again?" to "Are Ms. O'Malley's sinuses flairing up again?". ;)

Comment: @spender. If you're correcting that, then also correct the spelling of 'flaring' ;)

Comment: So, you want, after a quote, to continue to print the text until there is a dot?

Comment: @MethodMan A logical sequitur of your statement is that all problems for which there are existing solutions are easy. Hmm.

Comment: @MethodMan I think you did not understand the question. Please read it again, more thoroughly this time. I do not need help with the coding itself and I already understand how to use basic string manipulation code such as what you mentioned, and general "help" such as telling someone to look for "a third party library" or "use google" is not helpful. I want some help with the logic/algorithm itself. When you understand the problem in the question and you have a working solution, feel free to share. Thanks.

Comment: @sinsro I understand the question and how about showing what code you have so that we can see what the `logic` issue's are that you are struggling with.. this is not a code factory site..!

Comment: @stuartd Thank you, SharpNLP looks promising. I will look into it

Comment: @MethodMan Updated with the current code which works when the quote characters are different from the apostrophe characters.

Comment: @Ian H yes, after a quote the sentence should terminate as usual, based on any !,.\n character. So the trick is to find out when the character pointer is inside the quote.